# Why do I get 'use: command not found' when I run my Perl script?

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl. And I have used following code from one forum to connect to one of the server. but throwing error messages

```
[root@Cus]# cat tt.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::Telnet;
$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>2, Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('10.0.0.28');
$telnet->waitfor('/login:/');
$telnet->print('administrator');
$telnet->waitfor('/Password:/');
$telnet->print('test');
$telnet->waitfor('/switch8-12>/');
$telnet->print('whoamI');
$output=$telnet->waitfor('/switch8-12>/');
print $output;
```

But throwing following error messages.

```
[root@Cus]# ./tt.pl
./tt.pl: line 3: use: command not found
./tt.pl: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./tt.pl: line 4: `$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>2, Errmode=>'die');'
```

Comment: Those are shell errors, not Perl errors. Can you tell us which setup you are using?

Comment: It looks like there is a `CR` in the beginning. Post the output of `xxd tt.pl` or `od tt.pl`.

Answer (score 21):

My guess is that you're using a weird flavour of unix that doesn't respect the `#!` line, and is trying to run the script via the shell instead of via perl.

Another reason why this might happen is if `tt.pl` starts with a blank line.  The `#!` must appear at the very start of the file.

Try running `perl tt.pl` and see what happens.

Comment: What does "perl -v" show? Is it possible that you have something called "perl" on your path which isn't actually a Perl interpreter? (Bit of a long-shot, I admit.)

Comment: I had the same problem and this using perl in front of my file worked for me. What does this mean ?

Answer (score 4):

I had similar error messages and found the reason to be that the perl file was using the wrong character encoding (don't ask me why this mattered to perl). Perl was installed correctly, paths were in order, script syntax was perfect (I even got the "use: command not found" error for a one line "Hello World!" script). Check that tt.pl is UTF8 no-BOM.

Comment: Yes if you save with a tool (such as windows notepad) it can add a BOM marker byte. Than upset the #!, but not be visible.

Comment: Man, it took me the better part of an afternoon to figure it out at the time, since most text editors, of course, interpret and display the character encoding automatically "correctly".

Answer (score 3):

As one comment stated "It looks like there is a CR in the beginning".
If you are here hopelessly...
then run `d2u script.pl`

`d2u` --> dos to unix.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#!/usr/bin/env perl` at top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see these lines at the top of your script, which are *essential* for all perl modules and scripts:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You didn't say which environment this is running in -- are you using bash on linux? Whatever shell you are using does not understand the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/perl`), and is trying to execute the script in its own language rather than invoking Perl to run it.

Try using /bin/bash, and then your shebang line will work. Or, simply invoke perl explicitly: `perl tt.pl`.

Comment: [root@CusCent5U2-64CX gannu]# perl tt.pl
Can't locate Net/Telnet.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7/x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.7 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.6 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.5 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at tt.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at tt.pl line 5.
[root@CusCent5U2-64CX gannu]# ./tt.pl
./tt.pl: line 3: use: command not found
./tt.pl: line 4: use: command not found
./tt.pl: line 5: use: command not found

Comment: ./tt.pl: line 5: use: command not found
./tt.pl: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./tt.pl: line 6: `$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>2, Errmode=>'die');'
[root@CusCent5U2-64CX gannu]#

Comment: @chiran The required libraries are not installed on `CusCent5U2-64CX` Either use the OS's package management tools to install them or use `cpan`. Also, read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html **AND** http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2010/03/24/9983984.aspx

Comment: Add clarifying information and updates to your answer. Don't hide them in comments.

Comment: The answer to your "Can't locate..." problem is in many places on Stackoverflow. Try the SO serach box :)

Comment: Those lines are not "essential". Not using them is still the default.

Comment: @ONOZ it is considered very poor practice to omit those lines. It is not the default at all.

Comment: If it's the default, why do you have to type those lines? If it was default you'd have to do something to *not* use them.

Comment: @ONOZ `use strict` comes in automatically when you `use 5.10;`, but otherwise they're not default for back-compatibility preservation, which perl takes very seriously.

Answer (score 0):

The same happens in case if the `/usr/bin/perl` file is empty

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that there was no perl at #!/usr/bin/perl. neither perl -v or /usr/bin/perl -v were working.

I did a find / -name for perl then added a symbolic link from /usr/bin to the real location

perl -v
-bash: perl: command not found
/usr/bin/perl -v
-bash: /usr/bin/perl: No such file or directory

find / -name perl
/opt/ISS/bin/perl5/perl
/opt/ISS/bin/perl

ln -s /opt/ISS/bin/perl /usr/bin/perl
perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 1 (v5.14.1) built for x86_64-linux

Copyright 1987-2011, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

/usr/bin/perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 1 (v5.14.1) built for x86_64-linux

Copyright 1987-2011, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.